# Position in ncurses a pad below a window in c++

Tags: c++, window, ncurses, pad

I create 3 windows on top of the standard screen, with screen-width columns and one row height with:

```
WINDOW* pWindow = newwin(0, COLS - 1, windowNr, 0); // windowNr 0 - 2
```

Which renders normally as consequitive windows:

```
----------------------------0 Window----------------------------
----------------------------1 Window----------------------------
----------------------------2 Window----------------------------
```

My problem is under the last created window I want a pad which I create 
with:

```
WINDOW* pPad = newpad(LINES - 3, COLS - 1); // 3 because of the three pWindows
```

But `pad` is rendered above all `pWindows`:

```
----------------------------0 Pad----------------------------
----------------------------0 Pad----------------------------
----------------------------0 Pad----------------------------
```

How can I position the pad below the last window that the output is:

```
----------------------------0 Window----------------------------
----------------------------1 Window----------------------------
----------------------------2 Window----------------------------
------------------------------0 Pad-----------------------------
------------------------------0 Pad-----------------------------
------------------------------0 Pad-----------------------------
```

The `newpad` has unfortunately no (y,x) cooridnates as `newwin` has. To simply fill the pad with debug content I do:

```
werase(pPad); // Clear window, https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html
wmove(pPad, 0, 0); // Moves cursor in pad to y,x

for(int c = 0; c < 40; c++){
    string s = to_string(c) + ".\n";
    wprintw(pPad, s.c_str());
}

prefresh(pPad, 0, 0, 0, 0, maxRows, maxCols);
```

I also put different values in `prefresh`, its viewport scrolling or rather refreshing works perfectly as described in the documentation.

Comment: You could try `subpad` (in a window) rather than `newpad`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I don't know if this is allowed or good practice as the docs https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html say `The  subpad routine creates and returns a pointer to a subwindow within a pad with the given number of lines, nlines, and columns, ncols.` **within a pad** makes me wonder. But your answer gave me a different idea, see my accepeted answer I'm about to write.

Comment: Why the downgrading of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep the `pad` content in memory and render only one single window as:

```
----------------------------0 Window----------------------------
----------------------------1 Window----------------------------
----------------------------2 Window----------------------------
----------------------------3 Window----------------------------
----------------------------3 Window----------------------------
----------------------------3 Window----------------------------
```

This enables mimicing a pad, since in `3 Window` only the viewpoint of my data is rendered as lines. Scrolling can be simulated by changeing the range or index in my data structure and rerender only one `3 Window` line if a line got selected and the whole window if scroll in- or decreases the memory viewport index. This way a pad is simulaed and I avoid the different ncurses calls as `prefresh, pnoutrefresh, pechochar` etc.  and can use only window, `wrefresh`, calls. As an example, a scroll down would change:

```
----------------------------3 Window-index 0--------------------
----------------------------3 Window-index 1--------------------
----------------------------3 Window-index 2--------------------
```

to

```
----------------------------3 Window-index 1--------------------
----------------------------3 Window-index 2--------------------
----------------------------3 Window-index 3--------------------
```

and so on and so forth. In the ncurses API, windows seam to have more features, I can use all of them too instead of having possible future constraints by using `pads` now.

I'm sure, the author of ncurses had his reasons, but I only would have made an API of ncurses with one window type with a flag to enable pad functionality. Pads seam unneccessarly cumbersome and reduced to me.